# Create Bootstrap TreeView with JSON

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have JSON like this and I want to create bootstrap treeview, but I cannot figure it out how to do it.

```
[
  {
    "text": "n1",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "text": "next",
        "nodes": []
      },
      {
        "text": "hello",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "test",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "text": "wow",
                "nodes": [
                  {
                    "text": "hhh",
                    "nodes": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "fajno",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "abb",
            "nodes": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here i have this json in script:

```
var value = document.getElementById("value").value;
```

and then try to create treeview:

```
$('#treeview2').treeview({
            data: value
        });
```

in html:

```
 <h2>Collapsed</h2>
     <div id="treeview2" class=""></div>
```

nothing is shown except h2 text.
How should this json look like to create bootstrap treeview?

Comment: you need to include the `treeview()` script, most likely from a CDN

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make sure you add the necessary link and script tags and in the appropriate order

The data means nothing without the code and styling

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>
```

Run this snippet to see your treeview

```js
$(function(){
var tvData = [
  {
    "text": "n1",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "text": "next",
        "nodes": []
      },
      {
        "text": "hello",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "test",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "text": "wow",
                "nodes": [
                  {
                    "text": "hhh",
                    "nodes": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "fajno",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "abb",
            "nodes": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

$('#treeview1').treeview({data:tvData});

});
```

```css
#treeview1{width:200px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>


<div id="treeview1" class="treeview"></div>
```